# PromiseRejectionEvent occurence depends on the reject parameter type (primitive vs Error)

Tags: javascript

**CODE 1:**

```
function unhandledrejection(event)
{
    console.log("unhandledrejection: ", event.promise);
    console.log("unhandledrejection: ", event.reason);
}
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', unhandledrejection);

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>reject(new Error("Oops")));

promise.then(value=>console.log(value));
```

**Debug console**:

Uncaught Error: Oops

**CODE 2**

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>reject("result"));

promise.then(value=>console.log(value));
```

**Debug console**:

unhandledrejection: Promise...

unhandledrejection: result

Uncaught result

So why does string in rejection send PromiseRejectionEvent but Error does not?

Comment: must be a chrome/chromium bug - worlds most popular browser means they don't need to make it work properly any more

Comment: I cannot reproduce with this code in a HTML file, but can reproduce with this code in DevTools. So it seems this is the same issue as in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1111093

Comment: Thanks. My HTML reproduces the "bug" in Edge and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the different behavior you describe. For me, both cases seem consistent. I've tried this in Chrome and Firefox.

Let's consider these two rejected promises:

```js
Promise.reject( 'bad' )
Promise.reject( new Error('also bad') )
```

Unhandled-rejection handlers receive an event whose `.reason` property is whatever value the promise rejected with. In our first example, `.reason` will be the string "bad"; in our second example, it will be an `Error` instance (whose `.message` is "also bad").

---

I should also note that your example code chains promises using `.then`. However, if the first promise rejects, the `.then` handler *will not execute*. This is by design.